# What does "Yeah" mean

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), Dr Strange meets Sinister Strange, who is guarding Darhold:

> Sinister Strange: Here's the deal. I'll let you use the Darkhold  if
> you give me your Christine.
>
> Dr Strange: **Yeah**. I don't think she's gonna go for that.
>
> Sinister Strange: No? Didn't think so.

What does "Yeah" mean?

Comment: To the people close voting for "entirely answerable with a dictionary", can you find a dictionary entry that defines "yeah" such that it fits this context, and doesn't mean "yes" in response to a proposal? I can't.

Comment: Compare [Yeah, no | What does it mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100264/yeah-no-what-does-it-mean/). I think there are also similar questions on English Language and Usage.

Comment: @gotube [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yeah) says "often used sarcastically in phrases like yeah, right and yeah, sure to express doubt or disbelief". [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yeah) has an example where a person responding uses yeah then contradicts the first person. Collins refers you to [yes](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/yes) which includes "You can use yes to suggest that you do not believe or agree with what the previous speaker has said, especially when you want to express your annoyance about it."

Comment: @StuartF The Wiktionary definition is exactly right, but as it's user-edited, it cannot be considered "reputable", and I wouldn't want our users consulting it as a primary source, especially when no reputable dictionary supports it. As for the M-W, this context isn't sarcastic. With the Collins definition, this context doesn't express disbelief, disagreement or annoyance. The proof is that we cannot replace "Yeah" with "Yes" in the OP's quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"yeah" is informal/conversation for "yes".  It acknowledges the other person's remark but when  delivered with a tone of sarcasm or irony indicates that what the other person has said is not possible or is not true:

> Yeah. That's not gonna happen.

Comment: Yeah. It can be just be a way of saying 'I understand what you just said'.

Comment: Or ironically in the sense of "no". "Oh, sure, I'll just give you *my* Christine".

Comment: And then there’s the seemingly (but actually not) contradictory “Yeah, no,” which means something like, “I get what you’re saying, but there ain’t no way **that**’s gonna happen.”

Comment: And I shouldn’t fail to mention the (likely apocryphal) story about the mathematician at a lecture who asks, “Of course, negating a negated statement results in a positive, but it doesn’t work the other way around,” only to be heckled by another voice in the crowd, “Yeah, yeah.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I was actually at a lecture/presentation by a guest speaker where that happened.

Comment: @paultanenbaum It wasn't a mathematician though but a philosopher of language. It's been a very long time and I can't remember his name, and the college newspaper archives go back only to the mid 1990s. This would have been in the late 1970s, probably 1977. The lecture was very well attended, hundreds of people in the auditorium, mostly from colleges and universities in the Philadelphia area. Coulda been a copycat heckler :-)